# unsetChild method is not work in magento 1 layout

Tags: magento, layout

I tried to use the code below with no success:

```
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild">
        <name>product.info.sharing</name>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Image 1 : for child block
[image: Image 1 : for child block]

Image 2 :for Parent block
[image: Image 2 :for Parent block]

Comment: This is My Code:
 <reference name="right"><action method="unsetChild"><name>product.info.sharing</name></action> </reference> 
but it is not worked...

Comment: Can you please tell what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Remove Social Sharing Buttons in Product page of magento 1

Comment: IS YOUR BLOCK LOAD IN RIGHT SIDEBAR ?

Comment: YES ..!! block load in right sidebar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" -it is sub block of " product.info" & "product.info.sharing" means sharing.phtml file is appended inside "product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" this so.. i have put this name in reference and my i got it my Solution... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on template path hints and see from which template file it is coming.

then you can search that in catalog.xml of your theme and see the name used in `as`. check the parent block, use his name in reference tag, and in  tag use the value in `as` tag of original block.

Add `local.xml` in your layout folder, try this with your values

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="product.info"> 
           <action method="unsetChild"><name>sharing</name></action>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

clear the cache.

Comment: Not Worked for me...!!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<layout version="0.1.0"> 
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info"> 
             <action method="unsetChild"><name>sharing</name></action>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>

Comment: Still Not works your code Please look  above images and help me 
Thanks ..

Comment: from img 1, check removing that block from there, if it affects the frontend. If it is removed then there is problem in local.xml. You can have workaround for it, copy catalog.xml in your theme and remove that block.

Comment: Sorry but it is still not Works & as per your suggestion i have copy catalog.xml in my local.xml but not works and product page display as two parent block..

Comment: I am saying copy catalog.xml in your theme layout folder, check if your theme is applied from admin panel and remove that sharing block from catalog.xml

Comment: "product.info.options.wrapper.bottom"

-it is sub block of " product.info" & "product.info.sharing" means sharing.phtml file is appended inside "product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" this so.. i have put this name in reference and my i got it my Solution...
Thanks.

Comment: glad it helped you .